# Google map styled map marker not showing up

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to set add a marker to a styled map and its not showing up for some reason. I've tried everything I know to get it fixed but it just wont show.

```
       (function () {
var map, mapOptions, styledMap, styles, marker, myLatLng;
styles = [
    {
        stylers: [
            { hue: '#00ffe6' },
            { saturation: -20 }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [
            { lightness: 100 },
            { visibility: 'simplified' }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'labels',
        stylers: [{ visibility: 'on' }]
    }
];
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.882895, 151.204266);
styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled Map' });
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map

  });
mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [
            google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            'map_style'
        ]
    }
};



map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
}.call(this));
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the marker before the map is created (so `map` is not a `google.maps.Map` object):

```
var map, mapOptions, styledMap, styles, marker, myLatLng;
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map
});
mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [
            google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            'map_style'
        ]
    }
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

either create the marker *after* the map or set the map property of the marker after instantiating the map.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/80rtj3bb/)

**code snippet:**

```js
(function() {
  var map, mapOptions, styledMap, styles, marker, myLatLng;
  styles = [{
    stylers: [{
      hue: '#00ffe6'
    }, {
      saturation: -20
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{
      lightness: 100
    }, {
      visibility: 'simplified'
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [{
      visibility: 'on'
    }]
  }];
  myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.882895, 151.204266);
  styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
    name: 'Styled Map'
  });
  mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [
        google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        'map_style'
      ]
    }
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map
  });
  map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
}.call(this));
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```